distribution of proof lengths for a particular statement
Given a particular theory of arithmetic and a (provable in this theory) statement $s$, we define a function $\theta_s$ that takes a potential proof $p$ and outputs 1 if it is a correct proof of $s$ and 0 otherwise. Then we define another function $|\cdot |$ that takes a potential proof $p$ and outputs its length in symbols. Now we can get a distribution over integers $n$ consisting of the number of proofs of $s$ of length $n$, $D(n) = \sum_{|p| = n}\frac{\theta_s(p)}{\#p \text{ s.t. } |p| = n}$. Do we know anything about the shape of this distribution?
I'm not sure this question is well-formed, but maybe there's a way to make it rigorous. My intuition is that it's approximately exponential, with a high density around the minimum proof length that sharply drops as $n$ gets large.

I deleted my answer since you adjusted the definition of $D$, but I think your prediction is accurate (given some weak assumptions about the proof system) again because of "junk". After any proof, we expect a combinatorial explosion of similar proofs, most of which are not of exactly the same theorem.
